# Is "come down" a phrasal verb meaning "lead" or "cause"?

Tags: word-meaning

> Although the majority of people in Crimea are ethnic Russians, the BBC's Mark Lowen in Simferopol says the outcome of a referendum is by no means certain - and may **come down** to a generational split.

<sup>Source: [BBC News](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-26483818)</sup>

Does the verb “come down” in this text mean “lead” or “cause”? I searched for it in Longman, but no definition was matched to the context.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one. You've parsed it wrong; the expression here is actually *come down to*, not *come down*.

As [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/come-down-to) says:

> **come down to something** (*phrasal verb*) to be the most important aspect of a situation or problem : *In the end, it all comes down to who wants the job the most.*

So, in this article, the writer is saying that the most important factor in the upcoming election is the generation of the voters. It could have been rephrased using the verb *hinge*:

> Although the majority of people in Crimea are ethnic Russians, the BBC's Mark Lowen in Simferopol says the outcome of a referendum is by no means certain – and may **hinge on** a generational split.

NOAD says:

> **hinge** (*intrans. v.*) (**hinge on**) depend entirely on : *the future of the industry could hinge on the outcome of next month's election*.

I can understand how this would have been tricky to find in a dictionary, though, because the words *come* and *down* both have multiple meanings, and are both used in a good number phrases and idioms.